# How to upload and download docker images using nexus registry/repository?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, nexus3, kaniko

I was able to publish a Docker image using the jenkins pipeline, but not pull the docker image from the nexus.I used kaniko to build the image.

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-app
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      hostNetwork: false
      containers:
        - name: test-app
          image: ip_adress/demo:0.1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrypullsecret
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-app-service
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 32225
      port: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8081
  selector:
    app: test-app
  type: NodePort
```

Jenkins pipeline main script

```
stage ('Build Image'){
        container('kaniko'){
                    script {
            sh '''
            /kaniko/executor --dockerfile `pwd`/Dockerfile --context `pwd` --destination="$ip_adress:8082/demo:0.1.0" --insecure --skip-tls-verify
             '''
          }

stage('Kubernetes Deployment'){
            container('kubectl'){
                 withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kube-config', namespace:'jenkins']){
                     sh 'kubectl get pods'
                     sh 'kubectl apply -f deployment.yml'
                     sh 'kubectl apply -f service.yml'
                 }
```

I've created a dockerfile of a Spring boot Java application. I've sent the image to Nexus using the Jenkins pipeline, but I can't deploy it.

> `kubectl get pod -n jenkins`
>
> test-app-...               0/1     ImagePullBackOff
>
> `kubectl describe pod test-app-.....`
>
> Error from server (NotFound): pods "test-app-.." not found

> docker pull $ip_adress:8081/repository/docker-releases/demo:0.1.0 ```
>
> Error response from daemon: Get "https://$ip_adress/v2/": http:server
> gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

ip adress: private ip address

How can I send as http?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to edit /etc/containerd/config.toml and add your registry ip:port like this { "insecure-registries": ["172.16.4.93:5000"] }

if there was still a problem, add your nexus registry credential to yaml kubernetes file like link below
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use a private registry to pull the images in kubernetes we need to configure the registry endpoint and credentials as a secret and use it in pod deployment configuration.

**Note: The secrets must have to be in the same namespace as Pod**

Refer this [official k8 document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#log-in-to-docker-hub) to know more details about configuring private registry in Kubernetes

In your case you are using secret **registrypullsecret** . So check the secret one more time whether it is configured properly or not. If not, try following the documentation mentioned above.